# What do you call 'perpendicular but skew' lines?

Tags: geometry, terminology, solid-geometry

For example, the seat tube and rear axle of a bicycle or motorcycle. That is, when viewed from above, the seat tube would appear 'perpendicular' to the rear axle. But in 3d reality, the lines are skew.  I was wondering if there is a single word or concise way to describe such lines.

Comment: There's no special name, it's just that the projections on some plane are orthogonal.

Comment: That's not quite right, as for any two non-parallel lines there exists a plane such that the projection of the lines onto that planes are orthogonal...

Comment: "perpendicularly skew"? "lines with orthogonal direction vectors"? I'll note that an [orthocentric tetrahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthocentric_tetrahedron) (aka, an "orthogonal tetrahedron") is defined simply as "a tetrahedron where all three pairs of opposite edges are perpendicular"; of course, those opposite edges are skew, as well, and we implicitly agree that "perpendicular" in this context describes the *directions*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m$ and $n$ be "perpendicular but skew" lines. I suppose that you need to introduce a line parallel to $m$, call it $m_1$, such that $m_1$ and $n$ are coplanar. If $m_1$ and $n$ are coplanar they can be perpendicular to each other. So, now we have $n \perp m_1$.

[image: perpendicular but skew lines]

So essentially $m$ is parallel to a line which is perpendicular to $n$. $m_1$ is coplanar to both $m$ and $n$. I think that [Najib Idrissi](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/10014/najib-idrissi)'s [comment about orthogonal projections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069402/what-do-you-call-perpendicular-but-skew-lines#comment2175197_1069402) might help you explain the relationship by noting that if you project $m$ into a plane containing $n$ you will find $m$'s projection to be perpendicular.

EDIT: updated summary of *Najib*'s comment.

Comment: (+1) Ok now. The critical element missing from Najib's comment is that you can **only** use planes parallel to one of the lines.